# Find Derivative using Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

Use the Chain Rule to find the derivative:

$$y=\cos^3(e^{4\theta})$$

---

I just want to make sure if this is the correct answer :

$$-3e^{4\theta}\sin(x)\cos^2(x)$$

Comment: $x=4 \theta$. Also, you need to multiply by $4$, since $(e^{4\theta})'=4e^{4\theta}$
.

Comment: go through your books

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, you need to replace your $x$'s by $e^{4\theta}$ (what do you think $x$ refers to?) and append an extra factor of $4$:

$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}=\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\cos^3 (e^{4\theta})\\
=3\cos^2(e^{4\theta})\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\cos (e^{4\theta})\\
=3(\cos^2e^{4\theta})(-\sin e^{4\theta})\dfrac{d}{d\theta}e^{4\theta}\\
=3(\cos^2e^{4\theta})(-\sin e^{4\theta})(4e^{4\theta})$